# How to display AR model_viewer on iOS with file extension .glb (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, model-viewer

I'm using the *model_viewer 0.8.1* lib to render AR for Flutter devices, but I'm facing the problem that I can't render AR on iOS, and it works fine on Android.
In the *model_viewer* lib there is a property of *iosSrc* to show AR on iOS, but now the server is returning me a model of type *.glb*. It doesn't work on iOS.
I found out that *iosSrc* only works with *.usdz* extension, is there any way to convert *.glb* to *.usdz* in flutter, or is there any other way.
Thanks very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scene Widget to render .gbl model file but you have to update your flutter version to latest version (current latest version is 3.7)